# SQLite in PHP without SQLite extensions

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I was wondering if it is possible to use SQLite in PHP when the extension is not available (due to web hosting policy). Is there a pure PHP library for that?
Otherwise, is there PHP alternative for flat file database which I can adopt without going to MySql or MSSQL?

Comment: Web hosting without SQLite support is garbage. I think you should change provider instead of wasting time on something like this. There are many companies who offer basic web hosting with cost like 2-3 EUR per month...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the link pointed out by Andrei B: I published a link to my implementation of a database, entirely written in PHP, which aims at full support of SQL syntax.  It's an open source project, every suggestion and contribution is welcome!

https://github.com/morepaolo/PHPFileDB

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/mhgolkar/FlatFire or maybe stick with XML files (and related XML and XPath functions).

Comment: Both interesting solutions (I cannot upvote as I've just registered..) Anything which supports SQL syntax just like SQLite?

Comment: You might still accept the answer if it helps you. I can't think of other SQL-based equivalents. Depending on what access/software you have on the server, you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10264788/2527118

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave the question open for a while, allowing other users to suggest possible answers. Thanks again for your help